# Qt 5.2.1 how to reconfigure?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

When I configure Qt 5.2.1 the makefile says that you should run `make confclean` if the configuration should be changed. `confclean` no longer exists, and using google I found some postings which confirm this. I don't have GIT and using `make clean` also doesn't help.

Now I wanted to change the installation prefix but even after `make clean` the path is still the old one, even though configure claims that it is the new one, but after building is finished it still installs in the old path.

I now deleted the whole package and copied the entire clean sourcetree from scratch, so I can build with a clean version again, but this seems a big waste of time.

I'm using the opensource build compiling wiht MingW64, so how do I properly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, reconfiguring Qt means rerunning configure and so on. There is no shortcut around to it. Without git, the best you can do is make distclean, but it sometimes does not work properly.

Comment: Rerunning config is ok, but having make clean and rebuilding everything is a pain. I try that distclean, didn't know about this. Is distclean doing a full clean including the configuration?

Comment: @Devolus: yes, it is supposed to be the equivalence o `git clean -fdx` without git access.